# is there possible to show 2 max values in dataframe.pivot_table? Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

Dears,
I have dataframe with 4 columns:
-club name, formacja- player position, overall- skills points, player_url- name of player

```
a=[['club_name','formacja','overall','player_url']]
```

I want to search for 2 or more greatest/highest values of each club_name & position.

I tried to create pivot table, but there I can get only the max value:

```
b=a.pivot(a, index='club_name',columns='formacja')#,aggfunc={'overall': [ max]})
```

Do you know other methods?

Comment: please provide a complete reproducible example and the matching output

Comment: Can you share some expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the two largest numbers you can do:

`sorted([3,4,5,2])[-2:]`

It will output `[4,5]`

You can use it also in the pivot function:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'],
                    columns=['C'], aggfunc=lambda x: sorted(x)[-2:])
```